# How to take a list and make sure it is from largest to smallest by removing elements without sort()?

Tags: python, list, loops

I need to iterate through a list of over 1000 numbers and delete the first number if it is smaller than the next.

For example:

`[10,2,10,8,5,6,1,2,9]` would be converted to `[10,10,9]`.

Here is my current implementation:

```
oddList = [17,2,10,6,3,4,3,8,3,6]
for x in oddList[x:y]:
    for y in oddList[x:y]:
        if x < y:
            oddList.pop()
print(oddList)
```

Here, oddList should look like `[17,10,8,6]`.

However, I get the error that `y` comes before assignment. This is the last part of my program and I came up with this by trying to research `pop()`, list manipulation, and parameters.

Comment: this isn't the actual list.  the actual list came from a file and is 1111 numbers long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because you haven't declared the variables `x` and `y` yet, you've only set them during the for loop (it doesn't know initial values of `x` and `y` yet).

Also, it seems you have used brute-force search to find a greater element in the list. You *don't* need brute-force, and the code can also be optimized to `O(N)`. Start from the end of the list, and record the current largest element. If `current element` is `<` than `largest element`, then you can remove the current element (because there will always be a element greater than it on the right side).

Here's the new implementation:

```
oddList = [3,17,2,10,6,3,4,3,8,3,6]
maxElement = 0

for i in range(len(oddList)-1,-1,-1):
    if(oddList[i] < maxElement):
        oddList.pop(i)
        i+=1
    else:
        maxElement = oddList[i]
print(oddList)
```

On the `oddList` you get your expected result, `[17, 10, 8, 6]`.

Comment: thanks this did the trick.  I was wondering, for future reference, what if the first number in the list weren't the largest number? like if the list was [3,17,2,10,6,3,4,3,8,3,6] and you wanted the same output [17,10,8,6]?

Comment: @Juan: That actually did break my program, thanks for reminding me that. Yeah, I just updated my program to have it work, it was just a simple `for` loop bug.